# How best to filter entities exposed by ado.net data services on top of entity framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I want to expose a simple set of blog posts, tags and categories through an API provided by ADO.NET data services.

It looks easy in the demos: create your entity data model using the entity framework designer, add in the data service, point it to the entities, done. So far so good.

But some posts, tags and categories are unpublished (private), so I don't want them to appear in the data service. Where's the best place to filter them?

I could make a view in the db - but then the EDM designer treats the view as read only, can't find the primary key, and doesn't create the associations to other entities.

Or I could create a query interceptor to add the filtering at the ado.net data services level. But that just seems too far away from my domain model.

So is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use QueryInterceptors to filter your data futher.